# How to update VS Code in Fedora 27

Tags: visual-studio-code, fedora, fedora-27

In my work I have been told that need to use Fedora. I use VS Code and when I want to update I got redirected to download a `.tar.gz` file.

What is the right way to install the newer version?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well it seems I have found the answer for my particular issue according to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45500) from the official github repository it seems that there is a delay with the RPM packages, so waiting for them to upload the packages, a few days usually, and then run `dnf upgrade code` will do the trick

Answer (score 6):

Download the latest `.rpm` from the official website. And run `rpm -Uvh xxx.rpm` to update vs code.

I just used this method to update my vs code.